# How to install driver for airlive wn-370usb manually?

Tags: drivers, compat-wireless

first of all,
hi 
I'm new here and I would like to know How to install driver for [airlive wn-370usb](http://www.airlive.com/product/Wn-370USB)  manually.
I downloaded zipped driver from another computer and "transfer it" through usb stick.

But I don't know how to install it manually.
I type tar -zxvf and drag the file, and then it show more files. But what should i do next???

Could somebody write tutorial or video on how to do that? Or just paste me a link where somebody did this.

Thanks

sorry for making new thread if it already exist (but i didn't find it)

Comment: You need to show us the output of `lspci -nn` on your linux box. Looks like the chipset is realtek, but I am not sure which one. The [download page](http://www.airlive.com/support/firmware/WN-370USB) only has the driver for kernels up to 2.6.37, which probably wouldn't work on any of the supported Ubuntu releases.

Comment: Relate question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/252801/wlan-airlive-wn-370usb-on-ubuntu-12-10